# Javascript onKeyPress event not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Why does this statement work with OnKeyPress event of Javascript in C#.

```
 txtPassword.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "CheckPasswordStrength(\"" 
                + txtPassword.ClientID.ToString() + "\",\""+  lblMessage.ClientID.ToString() +"\")");
```

this code is working correctly, my problem is that i want to run keypress event not keyup event

Comment: I'm assuming that CheckPasswordStrength() is an existing javascript function?

Comment: ya, this is a javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on onKeyDown for Windows/MSIE.

Comment: Good luck on that bud, it's not going to work by what you want it to work as. The markup for my web apps are always dynamically generated based on the principles of the browser at play meaning, MSIE get onKeyDown and all others get onKeyPress. This is the only quick and easy way around your issue, really.

Comment: "The markup for my web apps are always dynamically generated based on the principles of the browser at play meaning". How do u gets that ?

Comment: What's your back-end language look like? Meaning is it PHP, Perl, ASP, Java?

Comment: If none of the above we can use javascript to write out your form dynamically as well based on the browser being utilized.

Comment: I m using asp.net with C#, Browser IE8/Mozilla

Answer (score 1):

You should check the rendered output by viewing source of the page but I think your problem is about double quotes. Replace them with single quotes.

```
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "CheckPasswordStrength('" 
            + txtPassword.ClientID.ToString() + "','"+  lblMessage.ClientID.ToString() 
+"')");
```

this will probably rendered as :

```
<input onkeyup="CheckPasswordStrength('clientIdhere', 'clientIdhere');" />
```

Comment: yes tehy work but the surrounding double quotes are the problem :)

Comment: this code is working correctly, my problem is that i want to run keypress event not keyup event

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta : Did you try to attach your function to onkeypress event ?

Comment: yes, I tried but it is not working, I even tried onChange and ontextChanged. But only this onKeyUp is working

Comment: between onkeyup, onkeydown and onkeypress events there is a little difference. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I want to work on onkeypress event. I know the difference among all. Although onkeyUp event can work for me but i just wanted to check onKeyPress event.

Answer (score 0):

Change "onkeyup" to "onkeypress?"  Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: I tried to do it, but when i changes it from onkeyup to onkeypress it doesn't works